# How to use Uber iOS SDK API in sandbox environment?

Tags: uber-api

I know how to use Uber-API in sandbox environment :

```
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/<version>
```

But i am not able to find how to use iOS SDK API in sandbox environment. This is piece of code from Uber developer doc...

```
ridesClient.requestRide(parameters: builder.build(), completion: { ride, response in
        guard let ride = ride else {
            // Handle error, unable to request ride
            return
        }
        // Ride has been requested!
    })
```

So, how would i know if this request is for real or sandbox environment?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Configuration singleton class that has a property `isSandbox` that you can set to `true`. The default is false.

```
Configuration.shared.isSandbox = true
```